# Get only a part of the stored document from pouchdb (not fetching the full document, just like how we read only the required columns of a table)

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

**My scenario:**

I am storing around 4000 documents into my pouchdb database.

Each document has two parts:

a) the summary part and

b) the data part (which is quite large in size around 200kb per document)

In my application I have a summary page  where i just display the summary of all the documents in the database. From the summary page the user can click on a document and then I show the full details of the selected document in a separate page.

**My issue:**

For the summary page i would like to just extract the summary part of the documents in the pouchdb. But I don't know how to do it without fetching the complete full document from the pouchdb(the main data part of each document can be quite large 200kb).

The following code is going to bring all the documents in the DB and am worried that it is going to create massive performance issues for me.

```js
db.allDocs({
  include_docs: true, 
 }, function(err, response) {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  // handle result
});
```

What is the best strategy to solve my issue?..
 Should I create a separate summarydb to just store the summary part of the document ? ..is it the only solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [attachments](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#save_attachment). If you have large 200KB data being stored in a document, and if you don't want to read it all into memory most of the time, then attachments will be perfect.

By default, when you read documents from PouchDB, it will only fetch attachment *summaries* (see [the attachments guide](http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html)). If you want the full data, you can use `getAttachment()` or any read operation (`get()`/`allDocs()`/`query()`/`changes()`) with `{attachments: true}`.

The "summary" operation is more efficient, because it doesn't even read the attachment from disk.